# Tablet resolution issue

Tags: android, resolution, tablet

I have a tablet motorola xoom with `1280*800` I have one image in my drawable folder in my project and when i checked the size of the that image its showing `1280*755` but when i used this image in my project.

And debugging it to know the size of it showing `853*503` and obviously it will not fit into the tablet.i have attached the picture here also.

I am getting the width and height by using following code.

```
BitmapDrawable bd=(BitmapDrawable)this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fish_normal);
int height=bd.getBitmap().getHeight();
int width=bd.getBitmap().getWidth();
```

Comment: put the image into the drawable-mdpi folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using images in hdpi folder.

//for hdpi

```
853 * 240 / 160 =1279.5 
503 * 240 / 160 = 754.5
```

// 750 + 50 remaining 50 px for bottom bar

```
1280 * 160/160-1280 //for mdpi
```

Therefore generalised size of your resources (assuming they are full screen):

```
ldpi
Vertical = 426 * 120 / 160 = 319.5px
Horizontal = 320 * 120 / 160 = 240px
mdpi
Vertical = 470 * 160 / 160 = 470px
Horizontal = 320 * 160 / 160 = 320px
hdpi
Vertical = 640 * 240 / 160 = 960px
Horizontal = 480 * 240 / 160 = 720px
```

Comment: Thankx amn..i am getting.Really helpful.

Comment: @raman did your problem solved or you still searching answer for your question?

Comment: @padma..its solved for the tablet 10.1 in which the resolution is 1280*800.so what i ddi now i put the image in the drawable-hdpi folder and the make it 1280*240/160=1920 for width and for height its 755(excluding the softbar) 755*240/160=1132.5.so now i made the image such bigger so that it will fir in 10.1 inched tab.

Comment: @raman why you place images in -hdpi folder change it to mdpi folder.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Honeycomb and Ice Cream Sandwich devices has the soft button bar in the bottom of the screen which takes up some of the screen real estate. In your case it seems like it takes 45 px (800 - 755).

Then you have to take the density into account. I'm guessing it is 1.5 for the Motorola Xoom. You can check this by running:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
Log.d("TAG", dm.density);
```

This means that to fill the screen you have to divide the screen resolution by the density to get the size you need for the image.

Comment: If the size of the image is 1280*752 then why while debugging it showing the size is 853*503 and even i get the dimensions of window using window manager it showing 1280*752.Then i think it must be fitted in the window.but it is not.