# xdpi layout and hdpi layout

Tags: android, android-layout

When I try to run my app in the emulator with a large res (1280x800) the xdpi layout should be inflated - but instead the hdpi layout is inflated.
why is that happen?
how can i force android to inflate the correct one?

**edit:**
layout-large/main.xml
layout-xlarge/main.xml

thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9224665/1012284

Comment: can you show the structure and file name.

Comment: see edit in the original post

Answer (score 2):

if your avd details is showing  `hw.lcd.density as 320` mean it will pick from xhdpi

if `hw.lcd.density: 240` then it will pick from hdpi

[image]

//you need to do like this:

`layout-hdpi` //this is wrong

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

Comment: Does the emulator run API level 8 or later?

Comment: @Royi check this http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: so what? whats your problem now you are facing?

Comment: i answer to devconsole.  the problem is that android inflate the large layout instead of the xlarge layout

Comment: emulator with custom screen size (1280x800)

Comment: if your API level is less than 10 then it will pick from large only. its not an tablet